# Did King Janaka feel remorse for marrying his daughter into the Ikshvaku dynasty?

Tags: ramayana, sita, janaka

Every father would like his daughter to be happy after marriage. However, Devi Sita had to suffer a lot for a princess after her marriage with prince Ram. Does the Ramayan has any passages that describe the state of King Janaka as a father on learning the fate of his princess?

Comment: Rama's family is the Ikshvaku dynasty, not Kurus. Janaka only appears in the Bala Kanda. He is only mentioned a few times in the other Kandas. But he himself never appeared.

Comment: Thank you. I've made an edit to the question with the correction.

Comment: King janak practiced karmyog so he didn't have any expectations or attachments.     Source:Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 3, Verse 20-21